# Outputting multiple arrays of data in R

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I have a code that loops through multiple subjects and outputs the run lengths of consecutive 1's in various arrays. The output is something like this:

```
Variable1RunLengths 2 3 14 12 7 8

Variable2RunLengths 4 9 8 12 4 7 3
```

And it does this for multiple subjects. I know how to output single variable to a data frame, but I am having trouble outputting the arrays of data I'm calculating with this code. Any suggestions?

```
GetRL<-function(df) {

 subjects <- unique(df.all$Subject)
 numsubjects <- length(subjects)
 runLengths.df <- data.frame()

 for (i in 1:numsubjects) {

     subj <- subjects[i]##names loop variable 
     subdf <- df.all[which(df.all$Subject == subj),] ##pulls all data for current subject
     ## pulls vectors within current subject for each task
     patrmdf <- subdf$Patient_Room
     compdf <- subdf$comp
     pertoperdf <- subdf$pertoper
     paperdf <- subdf$paper

     ##calculates runs of ones for each task, pulls lengths or all values = 1
     patrmall <- rle(patrmdf)
     patrmruns <- patrmall$lengths[patrmall$values == 1]
     patrmslength <- length(patrmruns)
     compall <- rle(compdf)
     compruns <- compall$lengths[compall$values == 1]
     complength <- length(compruns)
     pertoperall <- rle(pertoperdf)
     pertoperruns <- pertoperall$lengths[pertoperall$values == 1]
     pertoperlength <- length(pertoperruns)
     paperall <- rle(paperdf)
     paperruns <- paperall$lengths[paperall$values == 1]
     paperlength <- length(paperruns)


     ##outputs vectors and variables
     runLengths.df <- subj
     runLengths.df<- patrmruns
     runLengths.df<- compruns
     runLengths.df<- pertoperruns
     runLengths.df <- paperruns
 }
 return(runLengths.df)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A data frame is a poor choice of data structure for this, because you have arrays that can be different sizes.  I would try a list of lists.  Outside the loop, you would initialize

```
runLengths<-list()
```

Then at the bottom of the loop, you would do

```
runLengths$subj<-list(patrm=patrmruns,
  comp=compruns,
  pertoper=pertoperruns,
  paper=paperruns)
```

Then, for example, to recover the `comp` run lengths for subject `XYZ` you would write

```
runLengths$XYZ$comp
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems to work but it only stores the data I want from the last subject. Any idea why this would be?